# Why my private variable becomes null when I tried to access it from a method?

Tags: java

I'm trying to access a char array that I generated in a class. But when I'm trying to access this array in a following method, it becomes null. How do I fix this?

```
public class DnaSequence {

  private char[] dna;

  public DnaSequence(char[] dna) {
    /**
      * I generated my dna array here and has been tested
      */
  }

  public int length() {
    /**
      * This is the part I'm trying to access that array but got a null
      */
    return dna.length;
  }
}
```

This is the test code I used:

```
public class DnaSequenceTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] bases = { 'G', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'A' };
    DnaSequence seq = new DnaSequence(bases);

    int test = seq.length();
    System.out.println(test);
  }
}
```

And got a null pointer exception.

Comment: Post the content of the constructor

Comment: change formatting of code please.. also are you sure you are not generating local array from constructor?

Comment: Because it *is* null, as it was when created, and you have never changed it.

Comment: Do you refer to your dna private member as "this.dna" in your constructor? Otherwise you are manipulating your parameter and not your private member.

Comment: Try `this.dna = dna`

Answer (score 2):

If in the constructor you don't assign a value to `this.dna` it will be never change its value from `null`.

Any reference to `dna` (whitout `this.` at the beginning) is referencing the parameter passed to the constructor and not to the `dna` instance variable

```
public DnaSequence(char[] dna) {
 /**
   * I generated my dna array here and has been tested
   */
   this.dna = ... // You need to assign to see it, probably this.dna = dna;
                  // that will set the dna instance variable equals 
                  // to the dna parameter passed calling the constructor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are messing up with the scope of variables.

The issue is the scope of dna variable.

In your function DnaSequence(char[] dna), you make use of dna variable which is different from the one you declared above.

The variable declared inside the class(above the method) is called instance variable,where as the one inside method is called local variable.
If you want to access instance variable having the same name as local variable,you need to make use of "this" keyword.

For instance:

```
public class DnaSequence {

private char[] dna; //Instance Variable

public DnaSequence(char[] dna) {  // Local Variable
/**
  * I generated my dna array here and has been tested
  */
  System.out.println(dna); // Will access the local variable
  System.out.println(this.dna); // Will access the instance variable
}

public int length() {
/**
  * This is the part I'm trying to access that array but got a null
  */
return dna.length; // Will access the instance variable
}
}
```

so without *this* keyword, if you are accessing dna, it wont update your instance variable, which i think you want to update.
So it will be printing null, as it has not been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I created my fields as you describe (String objects), then in my constructor, instead of assigning a value to the private variable, I was using the String keyword again, basically recreating the variable.

Check your constructor to see if you are initializing twice!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
Add a code snippet will probably help.